iPad Mini A1455 stops on T&Cs when trying to install any app from App Store
Is there anyway, I can still use in 2024 a very old iPad Mini A1455 (1st edition?) and install any apps from App Store?
I have erased everything and started as a new iPad. Everything went easy, PIN, Apple ID, password, T&Cs. Device is working as new (as it was working 12+ years ago), all apps are there.
Problems started when I went to App Store:
App Store → Tube Browser → Get → Install → Password → OK

This Apple ID has not yet been used in the iTunes Store

Review → Agree to Terms and Conditions → Next
Bam! That's it. Nothing happens.
The "Next" button becomes inactive. Then after approx. 3 seconds it becomes active again, but literally nothing happens. I can keep pressing "Next" until cold death of the Universe. No effect.
As mentioned above, except for being 12+ years old, this iPad is no in state as it would be taken of from the box for the first time:

I have completed full factory restore about five minutes ago
No configuration ever changed (except for providing Wi-Fi password)
No service or app ever run (except for App Store)
No actual operation ever done (except for logging-in with my Apple ID twice)

Is there anything I can do about this? Or the device must be trashed as not being usable at all?

I was faster with writing than I was with thinking.
The solution is as simple as:

Get any newer Apple device or install iTunes for Windows
Login, pass two-step authentication
This Apple ID has not yet been used in the iTunes Store
Review → Agree to Terms and Conditions → Next
Provide billing address and payment method
OK.

Then you can go to your old device and install whatever you need.
Keeping in mind, naturally, that for 12+ years old iPad with iOS 9.3.6 an attempt to install most of the App Store's items will end up with:

Unable to Purchase. XXX is not compatible with this iPad

That's the saddest part of this story.
